# nx.bipartite.biadjacency_matrix() - keeping track of nodes

Tags: python, networkx, adjacency-matrix, bipartite

I am using python 3.6 and networkx 2.1. I import a bipartite graph from a weighted edgelist and then I call the biadjacency matrix function and convert the result to a pandas dataframe to perform some operations on it, like calculating some correlation coefficients (the functions performing these calculations take adjacency matrices as input, hence my need of transforming my edgelist)

```
import pandas as pd
from networkx import bipartite
A=bipartite.biadjacency_matrix(G, nodes1, nodes2).todense()
A=pd.DataFrame(A)
```

the fact is that when I call `bipartite.biadjacency_matrix()` I lose the names of the nodes, the resulting dataframe is something like:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  ...  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  \
0    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0  11   0   2   0   2   1   
1    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   1  23   2   0   0   3   5   
2    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0 ...   3  24   3   5   0   3   5   
3    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0  18   0   2   0   0   1   
4    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0 ...   1  17   4   8   0   4   2 
.
.
.
```

so after calculating the correlation coefficients I can construct a network based on the similarity matrices I get but I don't know which is which and who is who. Any suggestion on how to recover the names?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of `bipartite.biadjacency_matrix`:

> row_order : list of nodes
>      The rows of the matrix are ordered according to the list of nodes.
>
> column_order : list, optional
>      The columns of the matrix are ordered according to the list of nodes.
>      If column_order is None, then the ordering of columns is arbitrary.

and from `pd.DataFrame`:

> index : Index or array-like
>       Index to use for resulting frame. Will default to np.arange(n) if
>       no indexing information part of input data and no index provided
>
> columns : Index or array-like
>       Column labels to use for resulting frame. Will default to
>       np.arange(n) if no column labels are provided

You deduce that matrix `A` rows are ordered using `nodes1` and columns using `nodes2`. To get the same order in your dataframe simply:

```
A = pd.DataFrame(A, index=nodes1, columns=nodes2)
```